# setTimeout seems to be ignored after submit

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do a basic submit and refresh the whole window after form submit.

```
   document.getElementById('form1').submit();
   setTimeout(function() {
       window.loaction.reload();
   }, 1000);
```

But it seems that setTimeout was not performed after form submit.

Comment: please paste the html part. Is there any action attached to the form?

Comment: Most likely the page is being reloaded during submit ... so the setTimeout doesn't exist anymore.  However, you have not posted enough context for that to be anything other than a guess.

Comment: You have a typo at `window.loaction.reload()`, should be location instead

Comment: Is there a typo in `window.loaction.reload` and it should read `window.location.reload` instead?

Comment: Why do you need that, the form submit might be triggering a page reload

Comment: The submit went to a new page, nothing after it will run because the old page is gone.

Comment: please paste the code with html.  comment `window.loaction.reload()` and use alert and try to find whether there is an error or not.

Answer (score 1):

Here setTimeout is worth less because form submit causes in a page load so, setTimeout never been called or I would say that is not completely processed by the browser.

As the page has been loaded again due to form submission. The events and functions again get registered yet setTimeout can't be called.

Comment: I think setTimeout should work if the script exists in submitted page. Because there will be no form submit function but setTimeout function..

Comment: Also, I think OP need form submit function inside setTimeout. (not reload) This might be what OP is trying to,,,

Comment: That's actually totally different scenario. As not much code and context provided that can be answered as such.

Comment: Yeah, but you may put that in your answer optionally/recommeding.

Comment: For your second comment you can find that at the start of OP's post.

Comment: But form submit reloads the page so it would be good to use setTimeout for that so OP would get that page in that time...?